# Kafka connect throttling

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I have a requirement to consume messages on behalf of a set of lazy consumers who just exposes REST APIs. Therefore, I am planning to have Sink Connectors which fetches messages from Kafka topics and does HTTP POST operation on the exposed APIs.

One of the key factors for consideration is throttling. What mechanism do you suggest for throttling the Sink Tasks to meet the tier SLA of the APIs. I understand that Kafka has client quota feature, however, what is the optimum mechanism to keep track of API requests/min or sec which would allow to adjust the client quota dynamically ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the best way to implement rate-limiting for your REST API would be in your connector code by blocking if necessary in `SinkTask.put()`. You may want to think about whether rate-limiting at the level of your `SinkTask`s is sufficient or you need it to be global (more complex since coordination involved).

The advantage of using Kafka quotas which you were considering is that the distributed aspect is handled for you, however I believe those can currently only be configured in terms of bytes transferred.

Comment: That is right. Kafka client quotas are configured at bytes transferred whereas the REST API throttling is at no. of requests. In my case, I would have multiple sink tasks running in multiple workers in cloud. When you say global, you are alluding to maintaining the count of no. of requests in something like a cache (redis) ? Is there an elegant way of implementing this via Kafka connect ?

Comment: Yes, using something like Redis or Memcached for maintaining the shared state you need for rate-limiting API requests.

If you are okay with potentially too-conservative rate limiting, you could instead just initialize a Guava `RateLimiter` for each `SinkTask` that you acquire in the `put()` method. The number of permits you give to the `RateLimiter` could be `(overall_limit / num_tasks)` (you could propagate the task-level limit when generating the task config from `SinkConnector.taskConfigs()`).

Comment: When using Guava RateLimiter, I believe we would need the same RateLimiter instance across the sink tasks that are running across multiple workers across say multiple racks. That is, task 1 and task 2 should be able to access a single instance of RateLimiter on which the acquire() method will be called. Btw, I suppose you are suggesting Guava RateLimiter as an alternative to a caching mechanism ?

Comment: Yes, using a per-task `RateLimiter` would be an alternative to using global shared state in Memcached/Redis/etc. You should not assume the tasks are running on the same worker, so I'd suggest keeping a `RateLimiter` per task instance with permits equally distributed between them based on number of tasks. This should work well if the work is evenly distributed across the tasks.